# Does DotNetOpenAuth support refreshing Expired Access Tokens?

Tags: c#, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I can't find any examples of using DotNetOpenAuth to **refresh an expired Access Token**.  Most providers don't use expiring tokens, however Yahoo is a big one that expires their tokens in one hour.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yahoo does use OAuth 1.0, so I figured out how to do it manually:

First, I try to use the token I have saved in my database.  If I get a 401 Unauthorized error, I call my RefreshYahooAccessToken() method, and try again.

Note: I have my own implementation of a TokenManager that stores my access tokens in a database, as well as any extra data associated with the token (YahooGUID, and oauth_session_handle) which is given to me in Yahoo's get_token Response Parameters, but you can easily modify it to work with a different TokenManager implementation.

Here's my working version:

```
try
{
    request = yahoo.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(YahooContactsAPIEndpoint, TokenManager.currentToken.Token, extraData);
    response = yahoo.Channel.WebRequestHandler.GetResponse(request);
    body = response.GetResponseReader().ReadToEnd();
}
catch (DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException ex)
{
    //is token expired?
    if (ex.InnerException is WebException
        && ((WebException)ex.InnerException).Response is HttpWebResponse
        && ((HttpWebResponse)((WebException)ex.InnerException).Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        RefreshYahooAccessToken();
        request = yahoo.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(YahooContactsAPIEndpoint, TokenManager.currentToken.Token, extraData);
        response = yahoo.Channel.WebRequestHandler.GetResponse(request);
        body = response.GetResponseReader().ReadToEnd();
    }
}


private static void RefreshYahooAccessToken()
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest
        .Create("https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_token"
            + "?oauth_consumer_key=" + TokenManager.ConsumerKey
            + "&oauth_nonce=" + (new Random()).Next(123400, 9999999).ToString()
            + "&oauth_session_handle=" + TokenManager.GetExtraData("oauth_session_handle") //this value is given to you in the get_token Response Parameters
            + "&oauth_signature=" + TokenManager.ConsumerSecret + "%26" + TokenManager.currentToken.Secret
            + "&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT"
            + "&oauth_timestamp=" + (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds.ToString().Split(new char[] { '.' })[0]
            + "&oauth_token=" + TokenManager.currentToken.Token
            + "&oauth_version=1.0");
    try
    {
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var returnStr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        var returnData = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(returnStr ?? string.Empty);
        TokenManager.ExpireRequestTokenAndStoreNewAccessToken(null, null, returnData["oauth_token"], returnData["oauth_token_secret"]);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //User probably revoked token.  Clear the current token, and request authorization again
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're talking about OAuth 1.0(a), I don't believe renewing expired access tokens is part of the spec at all, so I suspect you just can't do it regardless of the OAuth library you use.

If you're talking about OAuth 2.0, then yes the `ClientBase.RefreshToken` method will do that for you.  DotNetOpenAuth even automatically renews nearly expired tokens when you call `ClientBase.AuthorizeRequest`.